# Spring AOP - AspectJ Error: ambiguous binding of parameter(s) session across '||' in pointcut

Tags: maven, aspectj, spring-aop

I get this error when I run mvn package from command line or from eclipse.

The weird thing is that if I run mvn package 3- 4 times then the error is not shown any more and the build is completed successfully! Also in eclipse there is a red 'x' in the file where the pointcut is defined (in the package explorer) but there is no error when I open the file. The pointcuts. The two pointcuts where the '||' is used are:

```
@Pointcut("((execution(gr.diassa.dslibweb.data.dto.GenericGrid gr.diassa.dslibweb.controller.*.*(..)) && args(session,..)) || (execution(gr.diassa.dslibweb.data.dto.GenericGrid gr.diassa.dslibweb.controller.*.*(..)) && args(..,session))) && excludeInitControllerMethods()")
public void controllerActionForMethodsThatReturnJsonString(HttpSession session) {

}

@Pointcut("((execution(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView gr.diassa.dslibweb.controller.*.*(..)) && args(session,..)) || (execution(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView gr.diassa.dslibweb.controller.*.*(..)) && args(..,session))) && excludeInitControllerMethods()")
public void controllerActionForMethodsThatReturnModelAndView(HttpSession session) {

}
```

I did not find anything similar anywhere, anyone has dealt with this before?

Answer (score 4):

This is both a valid problem pointed out by the compiler, but also a shortcoming of AspectJ from a practical POV.

The point to note is: you are not only using a pointcut to bind an advice, but at the same time you attempt to pick up some parameter value from the matching pointcut. Now the problem is that you're defining two alternative scenarios (with `||`) -- unfortunately it *might* happen that both scenarios apply. This wouldn't be a problem for matching and defining an advice. But since you want to pick a parameter value, AspectJ does not know what to do when *both* branches are valid.

In your example, there *might* be a method which takes *two different* `session` parameters at the begin and the end of the parameter list. Such a method would match both alternative branches of the pointcut. Which session is AspectJ assumed to return in this case??

While all of this is logically sane and correct, from a practical POV this often turns out as a shortcoming, though.

- typically -- and quite common when you start writing such pointcuts -- you just happen to know that the specific object you want is always the same, or at least the differences don't matter. Or you're assuming that you get the match from the first applicable branch ("short circuit evaluation") and don't care for further matches
- in all cases I've hit, AspectJ was *not able* to figure out that two branches are disjoint, even in cases where this could be derived statically.
- see also this Bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=121805 (reported 2005, reopened 2014). It looks like implementing this stuff is tricky and hard to get right. This Bug might also be the explanation why this issue is not detected consistently (as it should be)

So the only remedy is to split your pointcut into a distinct pointcut for each branch and to write an separate advice *for each and every branch*. Typically you want to delegate to a common implementation method from all these advices. Uggly, but gets you around this problem in practice